# Make click of non-label description text check/uncheck preceding form checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

Using CMS with very prescriptive components, and doesn't allow anything more than basic label on form checkboxes. Would like descriptive text in following div to also check/uncheck preceding checkbox using Javascript/JQuery. Example HTML:

```
<form>

<input id="chicken" name="food" class="" type="checkbox">
    <label for="chicken" class="checkbox">
        Chicken a la King
    </label>

<div class="desc" id="chicken-desc">
        A dish consisting of diced chicken in a cream sauce, and often with sherry, mushrooms, and vegetables, served over rice, pasta, or bread. 
</div>

</form>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/t8d32vaL/4/

Solution that could handle multiple checkboxes simply would be even awesomer. Thanks!

Comment: Why not using also a label? check out my updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/t8d32vaL/5/)

Comment: And if it have to be a js solution, you can take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/t8d32vaL/6/) fiddle.

Comment: That's a possibility. I am stuck sticking the description in a text component (also possibly inside of a container component with an assignable ID), and while I could insert the label HTML in that, I'm worried that could be lost when other co-workers go about inserting translated text later.

Comment: That's no problem of your question. The question is solved I think. Your "new" problem is a design problem. Normaly it is solved via an abstraction layer between the layout / design and the logic. So if you use a template language like TAL there is no problem like you describe.